# Pinescript V5 10 Most recent values

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to find out how to find the 10 Most recent values of my variable and not display the other variables.

I tried

```
new_pivothigh = plphigh != plphigh[1]
new_pivotlow = plplow != plplow[1]

plotshape(new_pivotlow[1], title="New Pivot Low"...
plotshape(new_pivothigh[1], title="New Pivot High"...
```

but that plots it for all because each pivothigh and pivotlow is a pivothigh[1] and a pivotlow[1] if it has atleast 1 pivothigh or pivotlow Infront of it.